# Opening .rtf file (created in Mac) on Windows show weird characters

Tags: windows, mac, rtf

I received a .rtf file generated in Mac and reading it on Windows (tried Word, Notepad++, WordPad) shows a bunch of weird characters e.g. ¤w§ó

Am I missing some fonts or what is the issue here?

Comment: I am assuming encoding or codepage problem. Try changing the encoding setting.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio rtf files contains ASCII characters only, and Unicode characters will be encoded properly so you can't change any encoding and readers also don't have such option

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio how do i change the encoding setting?

Comment: @xcoder in Notepad++ -> Encoding. Maybe also try to change the character sets to ISO 8859-1 (Notepad++ -> Encoding -> Character sets -> Wester European -> ISO 8859-1).

Comment: We would need to see the file in order to give good advice.